# CSS file not being loaded/applied when ASP.NET project is uploaded to Azure

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, azure

When I upload my project to Azure, I noticed that my CSS elements are not being applied on IE.

They are applied when I view the same webpage on my local machine AND when I view the project on Azure in Chrome.

I'm referencing the CSS file in my aspx with:

```
<link href="~/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I also tried:

```
<link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this is a compatibility feature in IE. Include this meta tag to turn it off

`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />`

I also stumbled upon another way to do it

Add an http header (in asp.net this goes in global.asax, also the chrome=1 enables chromeframe if installed):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest() 
{ 
    Response.Headers.Add("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge, Chrome=1"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That partially works, which is weird.. most of my styles are applied except for the font-size which is being set to "small" but still remains "medium". It's set if I copy the whole stylesheet into the .aspx file, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: I used <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE-10" /> and it worked =]